# Need to build expression tree for max date value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

I'm trying to build an expression tree for this linq query: so I can pass in a generic Entity:

```
this.EntityCollection.Select((ent) => ent.TimeStamp).Max()
```

I am wanting to create a class that takes a generic Entity and finds the max of its TimeStamp property.

I was trying something like below, but it complains:

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TE), "ent");

MemberExpression prop = Expression.
    Property(param, typeof(TE).GetProperty("TimeStamp").GetGetMethod());

Expression<Func<TE, DateTime>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TE, DateTime>>(
    prop, new ParameterExpression[] { param });

DateTime maxdate = this.EntityCollection.Select(lambda).Max();
```

When I compile, I get the following error on the last line of code:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Select' can be
>   called with these arguments:

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "It complains" is hopelessly vague. Please give us the exact error you're receiving. (Also, you can give Expression.Property a property *name* - that would be simpler than fetching it yourself.)

Comment: I get Error "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Select' can be called with these arguments:" on the last line of code there

Comment: What's the type of `EntityCollection` and what is `TE`?

Comment: where TE : Entity, new().

EntityCollection is IEnumerable<TE>

Comment: It needs to be `IQueryable<T>` to accept expression trees.

Comment: Thanks Jon that was it. Change it to this.EntityCollection.AsQueryable().Select(lambda).Max();

Comment: Well if you've *got* an in-memory collection, you could use `lambda.Compile()` instead. The benefit of keeping it to `IQueryable<T>` would be to perform the query in the db.

Comment: I see. That is probably better for me since it will always be on client. I am caching common database tables on client and storing the max timestamp to know if it needs to be updated so I have no need to run this on server.

Comment: Righto. I've added both options in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As per comments...)

The problem is that you're trying to use a mixture of LINQ to Objects (which uses `IEnumerable<T>` and delegates) and Queryable-based LINQ (which uses `IQueryable<T>` and expression trees). You can't pass `Enumerable<T>` an expression tree.

Three options:

- Convert the collection to an `IQueryable<T>` first:

  ```
  DateTime maxdate = this.EntityCollection.AsQueryable().Select(lambda).Max();
  ```
- Convert the expression tree to a delegate first:

  ```
  DateTime maxdate = this.EntityCollection.Select(lambda.Compile()).Max();
  ```
- Change your method to accept an `IQueryable<T>` instead of an `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer the [overload of `Expression.Property` which takes a `PropertyInfo` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348662.aspx).

Doing that, you could do this:

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TE), "ent");
MemberExpression prop = Expression.
    Property(param, typeof(TE).GetProperty("TimeStamp"));
Expression<Func<TE, DateTime>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TE, DateTime>>(
    prop, new ParameterExpression[] { param });
DateTime maxdate = this.EntityCollection.Select(lambda).Max();
```

It's just much cleaner.

It's possible that the call to [`Type.GetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) is not returning anything, and that is giving you the error.  Remember, the property name passed as a parameter has to be public, otherwise, you need to use the [overload of `GetProperty` which allows you to specify values from the `BindingFlags` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103.aspx) to indicate that you want non-public properties to be included.

However, I think there is a better alternative.  You should define an interface like so:

```
public interface IHaveTimestamp
{
    DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

That allows you to then define your extension method like so:

```
public static DateTime? MaxTimeStamp(IEnumerable<T> entities) 
    where T : IHaveTimeStamp
{
    // Return the max.
    return entities.Select(e => (DateTime?) e.TimeStamp).Max();
}
```

Note: `DateTime?` is used instead of `DateTime` in the event you have an empty sequence.  Also, you can create an overload that takes an [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) if you want execution to occur on a server.

The main benefit that you gain here is you gain compile-time checking of where the calls are valid.  This is *much* better than having an exception thrown at runtime.

Also, it wouldn't be difficult to implement; you are using Entity Framework which creates [partial class files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx);  because of this, it's easy to add another partial class file for each type that has this:

```
public partial class MyEntity : IHaveTimeStamp
{ }
```

Your original code indicates that you have the `TimeStamp` property already on each of the entities that you want to use this extension method on, because of that, you don't need to do anything to implement the interface, it's already implicitly implemented for you because the `TimeStamp` property *should* be public.

If it's *not* public, then you can change your definition to easily be this:

```
public partial class MyEntity : IHaveTimeStamp
{ 
    IHaveTimeStamp.TimeStamp
    { 
        get { return this.TimeStamp; } 
        set { this.TimeStamp = value; } 
    }
}
```

Either way, it's a simple copy-and-paste job with some tweaking of the class name each time.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. I am going to implement some of this like you say.

Answer (score 0):

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TE), "ent");
MemberExpression prop = Expression.Property(param, 
    typeof(TE).GetProperty("TimeStamp"));
Expression<Func<TE, DateTime>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TE, DateTime>>(
    prop, new ParameterExpression[] { param });
DateTime maxdate = this.EntityCollection.Select(lambda).Max();
```

You don't need to call `GetGetMethod` on `Property`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error after removing the 'GetGetMethod'